# iOS: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: range out of order in character class (Vue3)

Tags: ios, vue.js, safari, vuejs3

I am trying to go in production with my vuejs (Vue 3) website. Everything is working fine but yesterday I tried it with iOS Safari and was shocked because it only renders a white blank page and an error message: (There was no detail about where this error occured)

```
iOS: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: range out of order in character class
```

I went through my whole project but I dont even use regular expressions. Could it come from a dependency? Anyone else stumbled over this error message?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I dont know if it helps but this are my dependencies from package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.0-5",
    "@kyvg/vue3-notification": "^2.3.4",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.1",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.5.1",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "imgur": "^2.1.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.5",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.5",
    "socket.io": "^4.4.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.2",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "vite": "^2.9.12",
    "vue": "^3.2.31",
    "vue-axios": "^3.4.1",
    "vue-content-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-csv-import": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.16",
    "vue3-qrcode-reader": "^0.0.1",
    "vue3-table-lite": "^1.2.3",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
```